# convert data/time to tm/time_point against musl and glibc. Common way

Tags: c++, c++11, glibc, musl

I would like to convert string data to `struct tm` (c) or `std::chrono::time_point`. The problem is I wanna working solution for both standard libc (glibc and [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/)). I have tree standard formats that I wanna parse.

1. **RFC-1123**

   > Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
2. **RFC-850**

   > "Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT"
3. **ANSI C's asctime format**

   > Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994"

Is there any way to make it work? `std::get_time` has a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71556)
`strptime` work fine (and quick) on glibc but fail against musl.

Any idea? I don't wanna use stream like in `get_time`. But If it would be necessary that fine. (It's ok to use GCC5> and c++11 standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only, date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) can parse these formats into a `std::chrono::time_point`, even in the context of faulty `get_time` and `strptime` facilities.  It does require the use of `std::istringstream` though.  Here is what it looks like:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <sstream>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
parse_RFC_1123(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream in{s};
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    in >> date::parse("%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z", tp);
    return tp;
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
parse_RFC_850(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream in{s};
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    in >> date::parse("%a, %d-%b-%y %T %Z", tp);
    return tp;
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
parse_asctime(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream in{s};
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    in >> date::parse("%a %b %d %T %Y", tp);
    return tp;
}
```

This can be exercised like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto tp = parse_RFC_1123("Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT");
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
    tp = parse_RFC_850("Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT");
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
    tp = parse_asctime("Sun Nov 6 08:49:37 1994");
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
}
```

and outputs:

```
1994-11-06 08:49:37.000000
1994-11-06 08:49:37.000000
1994-11-06 08:49:37.000000
```

The parse flags `%a` and `%b` are normally locale-dependent.  However if you compile this library with `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` it becomes *locale independent*.  It *should* give the same result either way.  But from a practical standpoint, if you compile *without* `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` and you don't get the results above, you have to submit a bug report to your std::lib vendor.

If you compile *with* `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` and you don't get the results above, rattle my cage, and I will have it fixed within days, if not hours.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I did some benchmarks on your function. I can't understand why your solution is quicker than `sprintf` in RFC850 case. Even that you use streams.  Benchmark can be found [here](https://github.com/oktal/pistache/pull/102#issuecomment-322527542).

Comment: I don't get the same result with and without `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` for RFC 850. I would like to submit bug. But have no idea who is my std::lib vendor. If I use GCC 7, should I report it there?

Comment: What is more, my benchmarks was wrong, RFC850 parser fail and due to it was quicker than `strptime`. No it's slower, but works fine.